# How to remove white space from very begining of the textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, space

I have a text box on asp.net page, where i want that nobody can't insert the white space on beginning in textbox.

example: " Nick Carter" <----- wrong format , it should not be happened,white space must be removed.

"Nick Carter" <----- right format,

i don't know how to trim that white sapce from very begining from the text box.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's ok if someone puts a whitespace, what matters is that you need to remove it when he submits the form, do it with: `textbox1.Trim();`

Comment: This method does not work, because i don't know how many white space will user insert.

Comment: String.Trim removes **all** leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

Comment: And if you want to remove double spaces from the rest of the string, `string = string.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');`

Comment: textbox1.Text.Trim(); solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A javascript solution.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function trimTextBox(sender) {
            // keyCode == 32 is space(' ').
            if ((sender.value.length == 0 || sender.selectionStart == 0) && (window.event.keyCode == 32)){
                return false;
            }
            else if (sender.value.charCodeAt(0) == 32) {
                sender.value = sender.value.substring(1);
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onkeypress="return trimTextBox(this)"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note  that this will partially work for pasting. It will not remove the whitespace on pasting, but on keypress after the paste.

Answer (score 0):

Use following Regular Expression to remove white space.

```
string Result=" Nick Carter";
Result = Regex.Replace(Result, "\\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Asp.Net is designed according to MVC pattern, There are 3 points of interest to consider.

1. you may want to limit it only in the UI. (or view)
2. you may want to limit it in the code-behind. (or controller)
3. you may want to limit it in the business logic which process the data (model more or less)

(1)
For UI / View
You can use Field Validator to accomplish that.
The one that you need is the Regex field validator.
And you can read regarding of how to use it here:

[How To: Use Regular Expressions to Constrain Input in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx)

(2)
So while this solution will solve the problem in the UI side..
You might want to make sure that your server side controller also limits this.
To do that you can set in the ASPX code-behind a call to textbox1.Trim() or use regex commands.

(3)
Next, your business logic.. if you created POCO's you might want to put a verifying code in the property which receives the input, or if you prefer your POCO's versatile you can go to your business logic method and make the check in there just before you about to process the information from the input.

If I were you I would implement the field validator and do a 2nd check in the API method that is about to process the information, I would rather not alter the ASPX code behind or the model props.
But this is of course more of a matter of style or opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string RemoveSpaces(string text)
        {
            var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(" +");
            return reg.Replace(text, " ").Trim();            
        }
```

This is for all double spaces, and for start and end spaces